# Is ∅ equivalent to {∅}?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is ∅ equivalent to {∅}? I think they are, but I am not sure? If anyone could clarify, that would be great. Thank you!

Comment: "Equivalent" meaning here...?

Comment: I'm going to have to say no.. for one thing the cardinalities of the two sets are not equal.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51752/is-emptyset-in-emptyset-or-emptyset-subseteq-emptyset), [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/930848/why-does-the-empty-set-have-a-cardinality-of-zero) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193498/cardinality-of-power-set-of-empty-set)

Comment: No... one is just an empty set while the second one has just one element which is the empty set. So, first one... empty set ONLY and second one... there's a set with one element and it's an empty set.

Comment: I think this question has been asked at least a thousand times before.

Comment: No, absolutely no.... $\emptyset$ has no elements and $\{\emptyset\}$ has one..

Comment: Absolutely not! The set $\{\emptyset\}$ contains $\emptyset$, whereas $\emptyset$ contains nothing. Edit: @JearsonNarvaezRojas beat me to the punch.

Answer (score 9):

No. $\emptyset$ has zero elements, and $\{\emptyset\}$ has one element.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you are confused about notation.  Two common ways to denote the empty set are $\emptyset$ and $\{\}$.  Using alternate notation the question becomes is $\{\}$ equivalent to $\{\emptyset\}$.  Note that $\{\emptyset\}$ is a set of sets.  It is a set containing a single element, and that element is the empty set.  On the other hand, the empty set is a set containing zero elements.

Answer (score 4):

The set of an empty set is not an empty set.  $\qquad\{\{\}\}\not\equiv\{\}$

It has an element, even if that element is itself a set with no elements.

Answer (score 1):

No! they are not the same. Simple answer: The cardinality of a set containing an empty set is 1, whilst the empty set itself is 0.