# Subsets of the empty set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Having read Velleman's 'How to prove it' I came across a question I am not sure I can answer. He states that the power set of the empty set is equal to a set consisting only of the empty set: $ \mathscr P (\emptyset) = \{\emptyset \}. $ That is clear. He then asks what the power set of $\{\emptyset \}$ is.

What is $ \mathscr P (\{\emptyset \})$ equal to?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You simply need to list the subsets of $\{\varnothing\}$. One of them is $\varnothing$, since that’s a subset of *every* set. Can you find any others?

Comment: Related: 
[Cardinality of power set of empty set](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193498/cardinality-of-power-set-of-empty-set) and
[Is a power set null because it contains an empty set?](Is a power set null because it contains an empty set?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just Brian's words.

Empty set is a subset of every set. So, $\emptyset\in\mathscr P (\{\emptyset\})$. And for any set $a\in \mathscr P(a)$. But there are no elements of $\{\emptyset\}$ except $\emptyset$. So, $\mathscr P(\{\emptyset\})=\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$.