# Subsets of emptyset

Tags: elementary-set-theory

To follow up on [an earlier question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1366219/subsets-of-the-empty-set) and in order to improve understanding I would like to ask the following: What is the power set of $ \{\{\emptyset\}\} $?

Is it $ \mathscr P(\{\{\emptyset\}\})= \{\emptyset,\{\{\emptyset\}\}\} $?

Comment: yes. this is one of the most important results in mathematics (kidding).

Comment: Yes, of course. Sets $\{\emptyset\}$ and $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$ both have only **one** element. And $P(\{a\})=\{\emptyset, a\}$. You should not be afraid of nested braces

Comment: Sometimes to check that you have all the elements in a power set, you can use the fact that if a set has cardinality $n$, then the cardinality of its power set is $2^n$. This tells you that for any set of one element, the power set has only two elements, which have to be the empty set and the set itself, which are always elements of the power set.

Comment: @MichaelGaluza Are you missing the braces around the $a$? What I mean is $P(\{a\})=\{\varnothing, \{a\}\}$.

Comment: @coldnumber, yes, it was a typo.